# how to set Tab index for tab page windows form

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows form, inside there is a TabControl with 2 TabPages with TextBoxes. I need navigate all the fields using the Tab key(filling the first TabPage and then to the second).

I have set TabIndex for each TextBox in the TabPages, the issue lies in that while TabControl has the TabIndex property, TabPages dont have that property so i end up having selected the TabControl from the start(giving me the option the select 1 of the TabPages), and then going into that tab, but after finishing that tab it leaves the TabControl(leaving the TabPage i didnt select untouched)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to do this, but you can try using the last TextBox in the first TabPage to switch tabs:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Leave
  TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
End Sub
```

The other way would be by overriding the form's ProcessCmdKey:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
  If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso TextBox2.Focused Then
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
    Return True
  End If
  Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: This one looks like the best way to go, specially the second way, since the first one could be a problem if you are not using the tab (using the mouse means the user will fill things as he sees fit so changing tabs because he clicked that field first could be a problem. That second option is what i needed, thanks